# Time out Error on build in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: php:7.2-apache
  stage: build
  tags:
    - runner01
  script:
    - echo -e "\n Build da aplicação. \n"
before_script:
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git -yqq
- docker-php-ext-install mysqli
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
- php composer.phar install
```

I installed `Gitlab` using `Docker` but when cloning the repository it gives the error below. I could not find anything to help me solve this problem.

[image: connection attempt error]

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 Gitlab_CI:
  container_name: Gitlab_CI
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  networks: 
   - 'DockerLAN'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.docker'
  ports:
   - '81:80'
  volumes:
   - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
   - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
   - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
 Gitlab_Runner:
  container_name: Gitlab_Runner
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
  networks:
   - 'DockerLAN'
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
   - '/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
networks:
 DockerLAN:
  driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you actually access that repo - time out is kinda what it says - it timed out trying to connect to `gitlab.docker`

Comment: I can access the repository using `phpstorm`.